# Can't install Ember Octane on Mac; problems with NPM and NVM

Tags: node.js, npm, ember.js, ember-cli, nvm

I'd like to install the most recent version of Ember on my Mac with MacOS Catalina. I actually thought I had done so a few weeks ago (this machine is only three months old), but `ember -v` says that Ember CLI is at version 3.9 which is 13 months old.

So I entered `npm install -g ember-cli` in the terminal, but I get an error:

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    "Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
```

So I did what is suggested [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) and tried to install `nvm`:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
```

There's some output and everything is looking finde, but when I try to verify my installation using `command -v nvm`, there's no output at all.

`npm uninstall ember-cli` gives me `up to date in 0.031s`.

What can I do to get Ember Octane running?

*edit*: I managed to install NVM using Homebrew. `nvm -v` says `0.35.3`. But I don't find any information on how to continue from here. I still get the same error when trying to install Ember.

Comment: `nvm` is for managing `Node.js` versions, so that has nothing to do with you being unable to install `ember-cli` globally, but the error says `permission denied`, so have you tried running the command with `sudo`? That is, `sudo npm install -g ember-cli` - not really the best solution and you should probably figure out why you can't install packages globally without `sudo`, but you can start off with that. I'd also suggest installing packages locally where you need it cause those are easier to manage.

Comment: I haven't tried `sudo` yet because [the suggested way](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) *does* involve a tool like nvm. However, there's no info on how to continue once such a tool has been installed.

Comment: You could try `nvm install --lts` and then `nvm use --lts`, then install something globally, but based on the instructions you've shared, essentially it says to reinstall `Node.js` on your machine to try to fix those permission issues

Comment: can you show the output of `npm bin` and `which ember`?

Comment: @goto1 , the thing is I don't like to install things on my system unless I understand what's happening. When I do `nvm install --lts`, I'll probably end up with two versions of npm. But in what way should the new version be different and solve my problem? Can I be sure there won't be any side effects? @Lux , `npm bin` says `/Users/<my-username>/node_modules/.bin`. `which` says `/usr/local/bin/ember`

Comment: @Pida I suggest you look through the documentation for `nvm` to figure out what this tool is and what it does - https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm. The `npm` docs basically say to reinstall your `Node.js` version to try to fix the issue. `nvm` is a `Node` version manager, so you can install multiple versions of `Node.js` if you need it, so the `nvm install` command basically does just that - it will install the latest `LTS` version of `Node.js` which then you use to try to see if you're still having permission issues.

Comment: I understand what nvm is. To me, "[reinstalling] *npm* with a node version manager", is fundamentally different from installing a second version of *Node* alongside the default one, though. However, I installed the current LTS version of Node and activated it. Installing ember-cli 3.18.0 seemed to work then, but `ember -v` still said `3.9.0`, as well as `WARNING: Node v12.16.3 is not tested against Ember CLI on your platform. We recommend that you use the most-recent "Active LTS" version of Node.js.`. I had to upgrade to Node 14 and also do `nvm alias default node`.

Comment: @Pida if you're worried about installing multiple versions of `Node` on your machine then I suggest you delete your current installation and just manage your `Node.js` versions using `nvm` - that's exactly what it's for. Then install the appropriate version that `ember-cli` wants, you're not only limited to `--lts` flags, you can specify the exact version number. Once you install it, however, make sure you use the appropriate version, i.e. if did `nvm install 12.16.3` then do `nvm use 12.16.3` and `nvm alias default 12.16.3`. Ember's docs claim that `12.16.3` is the recommended.

Comment: 12.16.3 is the just version that didn't work. I had to upgrade to Node 14 (13 might also have worked) and also do `nvm alias default node`

Comment: @Pida it's interesting because that's what they recommend.

Comment: @goto1 It's recommended for ember-cli 3.10 and higher. Note that at that moment `ember -v` still said '3.9.0', so that message could be expected. The surprising thing is rather that the npm version from Node 12 couldn't install Ember Octane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem lies in your comment:

> `npm bin` says `/Users/<my-username>/node_modules/.bin`. `which ember` says `/usr/local/bin/ember`. Now it is important to understand the `PATH`.

Your `PATH` includes multiple directories and whenever you enter a commend it will be looked up in all theese directories. Now your `PATH` definitly contains `/usr/local/bin/` and maybe later `/Users/<my-username>/node_modules/.bin`. It definitly *should* contain borth directories. If it does *not* contain `/Users/<my-username>/node_modules/.bin` thats something you should fix immediatly.

Now however your primary problem is that you basically installed `ember-cli` twice in two versions with two versions of `npm`. At the time you've installed `ember` originally you didnt use `nvm` yet. And using `npm` with `nvm` is in some ways significantly different from using it without it.

If you're using `nvm` basically everything lives in your `$HOME` (so `/Users/<username>`). Also the folder where `npm install -g` will install binaries into, it will be `/Users/<my-username>/node_modules/.bin`. This is actually a good thing because this means every user can install its own things there without `sudo`. On the other hand if you use the global `npm` you will install binaries installed with `npm install -g` into `/usr/local/bin/`. This however either requires `sudo` or changing some permissions. We dont know what you did back then, maybe you *tried* it once with `sudo`, and since then this one version basically overwrites all other versions you may install later with `nvm` because `/usr/local/bin/` comes in your `PATH` *before* `/Users/<my-username>/node_modules/.bin`.

Now what you should do is get rid of `/usr/local/bin/ember` first. For this you do `ls -lisa /usr/local/bin/ember` because this is probably a symbolic link to somewhere else. Then you check where this link leads to and remove `ember-cli` from there. It is probably safe to just `rm -rf` the packages installed there. Next you delete the symbolic link `/usr/local/bin/ember` itself. Then run `which ember` again. Not this should either either fail or point to a different path. If it points to a different path you can verify that it is the version you want (in `/Users/<my-username>/node_modules/.bin`). If it fails you should verify that `/Users/<my-username>/node_modules/.bin` is actually in your `PATH` and that `ember` exists in `/Users/<my-username>/node_modules/.bin`.

---

Besides that I want to mention that `ember-cli` also has some interesting detail: if you run `ember-cli` inside an ember project it will search for the `ember-cli` installed inside this project and start it. So the global installed `ember-cli` version actually doesnt matter that much. It is basically only relevant for `ember new`. However for `ember new` you maybe want to consider to use `npx` because then you will always run the current version. So you could do `npx ember-cli new my-app`.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer. I'm actually not able to verify it myself (at least for now) as I went another way involving Node 14 (see the comments). I'm accepting it anyway.